# Loading dynamic content and rewrite URL on Hashchange event with Jquery Mobile

Tags: mobile, ajax, jquery

I'm building a mobile version for my website using Jquery Mobile API.

The framework provides automate AJAX navigation processing. But as far as i know it require "real" pages for loading purpose.

What i want to do is override the automate navigation process of it and process the hashchange on my own. But i can't not rewrite the url using window.hashChange, which is running well on my non-mobile website version :

```
$(function () {
    $(window).off().hashchange(function () {
        if (location.hash.length > 1) {
            PageSelect();
        }
    });
    $(window).hashchange();
});
```

I just only want to take advantage on jquery mobile interfaces, i don't want anything with its automate ajax navigation stuff !

I tried to disable it using ajaxEnabled() but got no luck.